# Automatically switch to a saved wireless access point with the strongest signal

Tags: wi-fi, automation

I have a wireless router (D-Link) in room A and a repeater (TP-Link WA750RE) in room B, *both having the same SSID*. Sometimes, when I go to room B and back into room A, my Nexus 5 (Android version 4.4.3) doesn't switch to the router although it has a stronger signal. It stays connected to the repeater instead.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>The "Tplink" and "Dlink" are only aliases. Both actually have the same SSID.</sup>

When I switch the Wi-Fi off and on again, it connects to the router. which provides much better speed.

How can I force Android to always switch to the strongest signal? Is there a setting for it, or an app?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only ask it to avoid a poor connection in the advanced section of WiFi settings, but not necessarily force it to connect to the strongest.

Answer (score 5):

Android 4.x will connect to the strongest available network when first connecting, but, by default, once connected, it will not change networks unless it loses its connection first. This is presumably because switching would involve disconnecting existing connections, and a second or three of no network.

Turning on "Avoid poor connections" in the Advanced Wi-Fi settings will make Android switch if the network reaches a low enough signal to trigger this feature, instead of waiting until it is gone completely.

One solution might be to set up a single SSID with two access points that support hand-off, rather than two entirely separate Wi-Fi networks - which is the way that this sort of scenario is handled in large commercial settings - but this depends on the hardware that you have.

Comment: Actually, both of these devices have indeed the same ssid. As I said in the OP, the tp-link is just a repeater.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not a networking expert, but it looks from your screenshot as though there are two networks with two SSIDs (one called "TPLink" and the other called "Dlink"). Presumably the repeater is creating a second wireless network, and bridging between the two?

Comment: Actually those are the aliases I assigned in the WiFi manager app so that I can recognize the devices on the graphs. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Most Android devices removed the auto-switch feature for APs having the same SSID because it is an Apple patent.

Comment: Can you give any support for that?

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used [Wifi Roaming Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heleron.wifiroamingfix) to switch APs that have the same SSID (using repeaters), use

When the signal level drops below a set threshold, it automatically switches to the one with the strongest signal.

Comment: Might be this one: http://www.heleron.com/android-apps.html Developer is clear about what circumstances the app is intended to work in, and when not. By description it is a perfect fit for this question, though there is note about some phones not supported. Switching APs does not appear to be seamless, the network is turned off and back on to hop.

Answer (score 1):

I use both apps: [Wi-Fi Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager) (which can give priority to 5Ghz network over 2.4Ghz) and [Wifi Roaming Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heleron.wifiroamingfix) (which can choose best AP signal once roaming).

My main router is a dual-band A/N while the repeater is only N. The setup is:

- A band: use different SSID from N band so "Wifi Manager" can give priority to it.
- N band and its repeater: Same SSID and channel so "Wifi Roaming Fix" can do roaming one client moving around.

I test with the VoIP app and my mobile phone works smoothly all over the house without drop/reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

[SWIFI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seah0rse.swififree) detects a weak Wi-Fi signal and automatically switches to a better network.

Comment: I use SWIFI too and it is a good app, but the problem with it is that it doesn't switch between APs that have the same SSID (aka repeaters).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be having a similar but opposite problem with Fios, Orbi with 2 satellites, and an LG V10 phone.  Orbi is set as an access point and everything has the same SSID.  As soon as the signal strength falls even a little below -65, the LG drops out for 2 to 3 seconds and then finds its own way back to the strongest signal, which is usually the closest satellite. BUT this is just enough time to lose a phone call I'm in the middle of.

The Android app "Home Wifi Alert" provides good detail regarding signal strengths and a great deal more information about my network.  Using this is how I was able to see exactly when/where the signal dropped and how totally sudden the drop is.  I have found that if I "train" myself to race through the place where it drops, I'm likely to lose a few words but often can avoid dropping the call.
Of course, this is less than an "ideal" solution :)

After carefully positioning the Orbi satellites using "Home Wifi Alert" as described above, I added SWIFI as recommended here. Since Orbi does allow for a Guest Network as well as the one SSID it creates, I added a Guest Network. Then SWIFI had two networks to switch between. With careful adjustment of SWIFI, I am now able to roam my house and SWIFI switches between the main Orbi SSID and the Guest SSID. Although I'm notified that a network has been disconnected, the other network has already been connected and I have not lost a call since.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WIFI Badger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.ruckman.wifibadger) app instead of "Wifi Roaming Fix" for the same SSID with NetGear Orbi.  Seems okay so far, although it would disconnect and reconnect when reaching a set dB from the router or satellite.

I found "Wifi Roaming Fix" disconnected for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 routers, one is D-Link DIR-816 dual-band and the other is D-Link DIR-803. The 816 is used as a repeater and is connected with my neighbor's router with whom I am getting internet and the 803 is connected with the 816 as an AP.

The solution I found is to match the security on both routers. The 816 has the option of automatic AES and TKIP, but I set it to manual AES. Both SSID names and passwords are same.

I tried the same thing with TPLink TL-WA801ND as an access point and I got the same result. Even the 816 is set to 802.11 b/g/n while the 803 is set to 802.11 b/g, but matching security works.

The settings page' screenshots are attached:

[image]
[image]

<sup>Click the image for a larger variant</sup>

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung Galaxy phones with the Samsung app "Routines" installed:

1. Create a new routine consisting of only the condition "Wifi signal strength"
2. Once this condition is selected and appears on the box, tap on it and choose the signal strength
3. Adjust this level on the slider. It starts by suggesting 40%. For me, 50% worked best
4. Next, under Actions, choose the following actions, in sequence: "Turn Wifi off"; and then add "Turn Wifi on"
5. Test it on various conditions, and if it does not work, adjust the signal strength level on the slider described above

It worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Where is this app sourced? I have a Galaxy phone and this app is not available on my phone, available through Google Play (the Routines app is really a task list manager), nor is it on the Galaxy Apps workspace that I can see. Is that AppName accurate?

Comment: @wbogacz Looks like this is limited to [Samsung Galaxy S10 or newer](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/bixby-routines/) and/or [Android 8.0 or newer](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/routines/routines-1-2-00-4-release/samsung-routines-1-2-00-4-android-apk-download/)