# Automatically switching WiFi

Tags: wifi-direct

I have two wifi networks in my house. They are very far from each other.

When I go to the kitchen area I loose connection to my main one in my room and it connects to the second one.

When I go back to my room the kitchen one is still slightly available. But so slow I cannot load anything at all. My phone (Nexus 5x) however does not switch back to my main connection but just stays on this sluggish connection.

Anyway to force it to automatically choose the strongest available connection?

Comment: Related: [Can Android switch to the Wireless AP with the strongest signal](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74754/16575). Also see my list for [apps to automatically switch to the strongest WiFi network](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_431).

Comment: this is not a wifi-direct related question

Answer (score 0):

As of now, at least on the Nexus 6P which is a Nexus and all of this should apply, the only way I've been able to stop situations like that where my phone is trying to connect to a weak Wi-Fi signal is to go into the Settings, tap on the network, and click "FORGET".

However, as far as current features in Android go, there's no way to prioritize Wi-Fi networks without an app from the Google Play Store.