# Switch to the best wifi: Android 13

Tags: wi-fi, android-13

Pixel 6a Stock Android 13

I have two Wi-Fi networks at home with the same provider - 2.5Ghz and 5Ghz (SSID'S are different though).

I am usually connected to the 5Ghz network but at times the signal quality degrades to the extent that 2.5Ghz offers a better performance. Unless I physically notice this and switch networks downloads and uploads are badly affected.

I have seen these questions and the comments under them:

- [Automatically switching WiFi](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/149492/131553)
- [Automatically switch to a saved wireless access point with the strongest signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/74754/131553)

I don't think my question is a duplicate because:

- My device is rooted and I am open to rooted means.
- None of them pertain to the current Android version.

**Things tried**

- I do not want to use an app since they require location permission which is an unnecessary battery drain.
- I haven't found any setting including in developer options that can do this.
- I found a Magisk module trawling the net but I don't trust it since it lacks any details or any updates

**So, is there a way I can achieve switching to the best Wi-Fi on Android 13?**

Edit: I am not looking for solutions that require changing router or installing any hardware

Comment: Typically this is handled by the wireless network and band steering based on signal level threshold settings... setting the 5Ghz threshold to steer to 2.4Ghz at around -65 to -75 dBm levels is usually sufficient. This does require the 2.4 and 5 Ghz bands use the same SSID. If they are unique, you would need to adjust the disconnect thresholds on your mobile device, which I am unsure how to do or if it's even possible.

Comment: @acejavelin good point. SSID's are different (edited in question) // I can't do anything at the router end since it runs provider setup configuration and I can't even access it//Tasker I understand can determine and adjust (from my scant understanding of what I saw on some forum and I am not conversant with Tasker to try)

Comment: @acejavelin on wife's One Plus 7,it is possible since it offers you to switch to a better network from among the saved networks. That made me think it is possible

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a design feature of the Android phones to stick to a network until it's just impossible to continue.

I used an app for a while but got sick of it and I have since installed Ubiquity Wireless Access Points and a Router in my house.  This does what is called an `active handover`, where it instructs the phone to switch to a different WAP.  It's the same method used in malls and airports.

It's either this or use an app.  I can't recommend any as I haven't used one for a few years.

Comment: +1 but don't agree with *It's either this or use an app*. On a rooted phone lot of things are possible. Few years ago there was an Xposed module that could this

Comment: Also, I am looking for a phone based solution only (should have mentioned this in the question earlier)